# Como enviar um json de uma Activity para um Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho uma activity que é adicionado um dado no JsonObjetct. E como visto no código a seguir, eu o levo como string, mas, minha dúvida, como eu pelo este JsonObject no fragmento para que possa trabalhar com ele, como Json?

Segue código da Activity:

```
.........
    objectJson = SharedPreferenceHelper.getScheduling(this);
    inicializeSetting(savedInstanceState);

    btn_1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglSearch1);
    btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn_1.setChecked(true);
            btn_2.setChecked(false);
            objectJson.addProperty("type", 0);

        }
    });
    btn_2 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglSearch2);
    btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn_1.setChecked(false);
            btn_2.setChecked(true);
            objectJson.addProperty("type", 1);
        }
    });

    btnContinuar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoSearch);
    btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SearchAskListFragment fragment = new SearchAskListFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("json", objectJson.toString());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.containerLinear, fragment)
                    .commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
           // Routes.open(getApplicationContext(),URIs.SearchAskFragment());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está é a maneira mais indicada de se fazer, pois a sua activity não vai precisar conhecer as chaves que seu fragment precisa e vc obriga que ele instancie com os parâmetros corretos.

No caso do seu ObjectJson talvez você precise converter ele em String para colocar no bundle e no fragment recuperado da String pro Object. Eu aconselho você já criar um objeto e converter o json nele para transitar facilmente por activities e fragments.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String param) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("someString", param);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Você conseguira recuperar os objetos salvos desta forma:

```
getArguments().getString("someString", 0);
```